# Can JpaRepository take entity description from *.hbm.xml files?

Tags: rest, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I write application using hibernate, spring-boot-data-jpa and spring-boot-data-rest.

My entity classes are not contain any annotations, and all orm mapping placed in several hbm.xml files.

```
class MyEntity {
    Long id;
    String name;
}

interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

Hibernate working fine, as well as all methods of JpaRepository like findOne. The problem that the rest interface provided by JpaRepository say

```
"PersistentEntity does not have an identifier property!".
```

I found that adding @Id to MyEntity class solves the problem. However, I prefer define orm mapping in hbm.xml file, not using annotations.

How can I configure JpaRepository's to consider *.hbm.xml files?

Comment: If something is "JPA" then it should NEVER take some proprietary stuff. JPA allows "orm.xml" so "JpaRepository" ought to support that

Comment: You are right, but may be exists a way to provide necessary information for rest layer w/o migrate all to orm.xml.

Comment: Have you tried putting your mapping files in the src/main/resources directory?

Comment: Yes, I did. It ignored.

Comment: Spring Data JPA scans the entity for an `@Id` or `@EmbeddedId` field, currently it doesn't take xml configuration into account.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem with JpaRepository using hbm files. JpaRepository  can accept hbm files if these are present in resource folder. In resources folder, create any folder say resources/hbm and move all hbm file to this folder. Now hbm files will be found by JpaRepository  and not an managed type error will be fixed.